# To have Description of the Body

Tags: feature-request

We discuss the Negative votes without explanation [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/698/86). 
I think it is related to many challenges generally in the SO framework.
In the [answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701/86), I propose how to improve collaboration here such that the users know how work between the body and the title.

I think the body is a place which tries to help the user to find a solution the title. 
There can be helper questions, one sided approach, anything that the user finds useful to solve the problem. 
I think it would be great if there would be the following description in the Description of the body

### #1

> This is your Sandbox - the Body. Make it match your question/topic in Title well.
>   Feel free to Use helper questions and diagrams to describe the
>   challenge.

or

### #2

> This is the Body. Make it match your question/topic in Title well.
>   Feel free to Use helper questions and diagrams to describe the
>   challenge.

**What do you think?** Should we include some description what is the body for users?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the relationship between title and body can be interesting (and almost non-existent in some Qs). However, many of the issues you mention should be clear from reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (but in rather implicit terms), for instance that the body should be used to clarify the question, to give background and maybe examples. I also think that the term *sandbox* should be avoided for the body, since it would give the impression that this area is some sort of testing ground. In my eyes, this is where the actual, well-formed question is formulated. The title is just what it is - a title.

Either way, I think an addition to the [*"Ask Question"*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page to clarify the purpose of title/body could be useful. At the moment, you mostly get formatting tips for the body, not nothing on what the body should contain. Of the two, I like your second alternative better, and would suggest something like (e.g. as greyed-out text in the question box or in the right hand margin):

> Use this area to develop your question and provide some background. Make sure the questions here matches your **Title**. Feel free to use examples, subquestions, figures and diagrams to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Title is officially "[Y]our biology question", not just title. I offered 2nd description for the body. I think the title should include the main question. The body should offer helper questions and/or cases to formulate the situation in some approach.